# Normal zip file created on server, corrupted zip file received in client

Tags: javascript, python, zip, jszip

I have a `Vue.js` app that is trying to request a zip file from a `Flask` server. However, when I receive the payload from the server and try to open it, the package I am using (`JSZip`) tells me that the zip file is corrupted. If I request the url through the browser, the zip file downloads with no problems. I think it might be in the way the zip file is generated, but I'm not sure. Why would the file be corrupted on the client-side?

client Javascript code:

```
const jszip = require('./jszip.min.js');
...more code...

this.filesystem.REST.get('http://localhost:3000').then(function(result){
    var zip = new jszip();
    zip.loadAsync(result.data).then(function(contents) {
         // Execution does not reach this point
         // Fails with corruption error before the then() call
    })

})
```

server Python code:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    playerFp = os.path.join(seriesMap[seriesid], playerid)
    fileList = os.listdir(playerFp)
    bytesIo = io.BytesIO()
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(bytesIo, mode="w")
    for file in fileList:
        if '.jpg' in file or '.xml' in file:
            absFp =os.path.join(playerFp, file)
            if '.xml' in file:
                stats = getJsonFormat(absFp)
                jsonfile = file.replace('.xml', '.json')
                zf.writestr(jsonfile, stats)
            else:
                zf.write(absFp, os.path.relpath(absFp, playerFp))
    zf.close()  


    bytesIo.seek(0)

    return send_file(bytesIo,  attachment_filename=playerid+'.zip', as_attachment=False)
```

This is the error I'm getting in the console:

[image]

Comment: Your server probably cannot send a blob. The http request is probably downgrading some of the character encodings.

Comment: look at the answer @rafafan2010

Comment: Encodings support

The async("string") method uses UTF-8 to decode the content. If you have a text in a different encoding, you can get the bytes array with async("uint8array") and decode it with a lib (iconv, iconv-lite, etc) on your side. To save a text using a non-UTF-8 encoding, do the same : encode it into a Uint8Array before adding it to JSZip.

Comment: Have you tried with one empty zip? did it still not work?

Answer (score 0):

Your script on the client is faulty. You need to define your zip file with:

```
var zip = new JSZip()
```

as opposed to:

```
var zip = new jszip()
```

Comment: I actually have `const jszip = require('./jszip.min.js');` at the beginning of the file. Should have included that. Sorry.

Comment: I am getting `jszip.JSZip is not a constructor`. The JSZip object is being created correctly. Its the read that is not working.

Comment: @rafafan2010 look at the syntax highlighting on your post. jszip is not highlighted. while JSZip is.

Comment: @rafafan2010 never use minified code unless you wrote it.